# Pass variables to switch via procedure

Tags: c#, cmd, menu

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the ints from `numberRequest` in my `switch` case and then proceed to use them with the `Addition` procedure. Do I need to scope my variables differently? Can I pass the variables to each other somehow?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input;
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
                numberRequest();
                int result = Addition(firstNum, secondNum);
                Console.Write(result);
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
        }
    }

    static int Addition(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x + y;
        return result;
    }

    static void numberRequest()
    {
        int firstNum;
        int secondNum;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 7);
        Console.Write("Enter the first number:  ");
        firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 8);
        Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");
        secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: `firstNum` and `secondNum` are local variables that only exist and can only be accessed from the `numberRequest()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like:

```
class TwoNumbers
{
   public int First;
   public int Second;
}
```

Then change numberRequest() to return TwoNumbers instead of void:

```
static TwoNumbersnumberRequest()
{
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 7);
    Console.Write("Enter the first number:  ");
    firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 8);
    Console.Write("Enter the second number: ");
    secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    return new TwoNumbers() { First = firstNum, Second = secondNum };
}
```

Finally, in Main:

```
…
case 1:
            TwoNumbers nums = numberRequest();
            int result = Addition(nums.First, nums.Second);
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstNum` and `secondNum` are local variables that only exist and can only be accessed from the `numberRequest()` function.

There are a couple ways to fix this. One would be to make them class member variables. Or you could have the function return 2 vars. I would just call the function twice.

```
static int numberRequest(string prompt, int left, int top)
{
    int num;
    // Loop until user enters valid input
    while (true) {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
        Console.Write(prompt);
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num)) {
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int input;
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
            int firstNum = numberRequest("Enter the first number:  ", 1, 8);
            int secondNum = numberRequest("Enter the second number:  ", 2, 8);
            int result = Addition(firstNum, secondNum);
            Console.Write(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
            break;
    }
}
```